# magento 1.7.x remove Sales Rules & Coupons for using database

Tags: magento-1.7, database, sql

I have direct database of magento 1.7.x and I have to remove all Sales Rules & Coupons using mysql **Query**.

I don't want to use any magento code even PHP code.

I have just need database query to remove all my Coupons form database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to `TRUNCATE` all Tables.

> TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely. It requires the DROP
>   privilege.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

```
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_coupon;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_coupon_usage;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_customer;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_customer_group;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_label;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_product_attribute;
TRUNCATE TABLE salesrule_website;
```